# Android 6 - cannot enter recovery mode

Tags: adb, recovery-mode

I'm hoping someone can save my sanity here.... I'm trying to install a new firmware on my daughter's old Android device - a wonderful Doogee X5 Pro. I really want to install some new firmware as this device is one of those that's sold on Amazon that after a week or two of every factory reset gets unwanted adverts popping up all the time.

When I hold volume down & power I get to a "factory menu" but the recovery option isn't there. When I hold volume up & power there is a recovery option but all I get is the android on his back and the phrase "no instruction". I have finally managed to get that ADB stuff installed but that tells me the server version doesn't match the client...

I have tried SP Flash thing but I found the whole process very confusing and it didn't work. I've tried a couple of rooting programmes off the internet but they both failed.

I have a little recovery file ready that if I can get to it via recovery will root the device and allow me to install what ever I want. I have two firmwares ready to rock & roll....

So if anyone knows how I can get the recovery option back on the factory screen or resolve the issue in ADB I'd be very, very grateful. Or point me in the direction of a website with instructions on either.

Apologies if this sort of thing has been posted many times before.

Thanks,

Ross